# Accuracy remains identical between Tensorflow runs

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow

I've been trying to utilise Tensorflow to gauge it's suitability for classifying data that I'm studying on a Huntington Disease project (not relevant to the problem, just providing context). Previously, I was using Support Vector Machines to classify my data, which were 'ok'. I'm hoping NNetworks are better.

Loading the data is fine, no issues there. After reading the documentation for Tensorflow, and following some tutorials and examples online, I wrote the following to do a very simple network example with CSV data. The data I use in this provided example is the standard MNIST image database, but in CSV format.

```
    datafile = os.path.join('/pathtofile/','mnist_train.csv')
    descfile = os.path.join('/pathtofile/','mnist_train.rst')
    mnist = DataLoader(datafile, descfile).load_model()

    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(mnist.DATA, mnist.TARGET, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

    ## Width and length of arrays
    train_width = len(a_train[0]) + 1; train_length = len(a_train)
    test_width = len(a_test[0]) + 1; test_length = len(a_test)
    data = self.build_rawdata(a_train, b_train, train_length, train_width)
    test_data = self.build_rawdata(a_test, b_test, test_length, test_width)

    y_train, y_train_onehot = self.onehot_converter(data)
    y_test, y_test_onehot = self.onehot_converter(test_data)

    ## A = Features, B = Classes
    A = data.shape[1]-1
    B = len(y_train_onehot[0])
```

All functional. Train, test and onehot arrays are all the correct size and populated with the correct values.

The actual tensorflow code is where I am most likely going wrong (?).

```
    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

    ##Weights and bias
    x = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, A])
    y_ = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, B])
    W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([A,B], stddev=0.01))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([B], stddev=0.01))

    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
    cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y))

    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cross_entropy)

    ## 300 iterations of learning
    ## of the above GradientDescentOptimiser
    for i in range(100):
        train_step.run(feed_dict={x: x_train, y_: y_train_onehot})
        correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
        result = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: x_test, y_: y_test_onehot})
        print 'Run {}, {}'.format(i+1, result)
```

Each output of this code always produces the exact same accuracy, and I can't figure out why.

```
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/local_device.cc:40] Local device intra op parallelism threads: 12
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:58] Direct session inter op parallelism threads: 12
Run 1, 0.0974242389202
Run 2, 0.0974242389202
Run 3, 0.0974242389202
Run 4, 0.0974242389202
Run 5, 0.0974242389202
Run 6, 0.0974242389202
Run 7, 0.0974242389202
Run 8, 0.0974242389202
Run 9, 0.0974242389202
Run 10, 0.0974242389202
....
Run 100, 0.0974242389202
```

I have went back and looked at the tutorials, and examples I learned from. The iris dataset (loaded in the same manner) produced a proper output that predicted accurately. Yet, this code with the MNIST CSV data does not.

Any insight would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**

So I had a few minutes and tried some of your suggestions, to no avail. I also decided to go back and test things with the Iris CSV dataset, for comparisons sake. Output is slightly different after use sess.run(train_step, feed=dict={...}:

```
Run 1, 0.300000011921
Run 2, 0.319999992847
Run 3, 0.699999988079
Run 4, 0.699999988079
Run 5, 0.699999988079
Run 6, 0.699999988079
Run 7, 0.360000014305
Run 8, 0.699999988079
Run 9, 0.699999988079
Run 10, 0.699999988079
Run 11, 0.699999988079
Run 12, 0.699999988079
Run 13, 0.699999988079
Run 14, 0.699999988079
Run 15, 0.699999988079
Run 16, 0.300000011921
Run 17, 0.759999990463
Run 18, 0.680000007153
Run 19, 0.819999992847
Run 20, 0.680000007153
Run 21, 0.680000007153
Run 22, 0.839999973774
Run 23, 0.319999992847
Run 24, 0.699999988079
Run 25, 0.699999988079
```

Values generally hover around this range, until it reaches Run 64, where it is locked at:

```
Run 64, 0.379999995232
...
Run 100, 0.379999995232
```

Comment: As a quick thing, try doing sess.run(train_step, ...)  - it's probably not the problem, but it jumps out since you didn't do 'with session'

Comment: Are all your y_ values 0 by any chance? That would make gradient zero and leave your parameter vector unchanged between iterations. You can debug by adding tf.Print statements to print intermediate values in your computational graph

Comment: Thanks for your input, I will look into these options when I have time outside of meetings (lots today, zzz)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that your train_step is not inside a sess.run try this. Also consider using mini-batching for the training like so:

```
for i in range(100):
    for start, end in zip(range(0, len(x_train), 20), range(20, len(x_train), 20)):
        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: x_train[start:end], y_: y_train_onehot[start:end]})
```

Comment: but there's train_step.run which calls call session.run(train_step) using default session, which is going to be sess in this case

Comment: Yes, this doesn't seem to change anything. Same output. I will keep working at this when I get some time.

Comment: Np, thought is was worth a try, esp the mini-batching as that would explain the slightly wild jumps, I'll see if I can think of anything else.